# How to only bring up a specific line when calling upon a script in python

Tags: python, variables, reference

so I am messing around with some python code and calling upon a script. I am helping a friend with a text based game. So, I have one script called styleslist, it has a list of variable declarations. I then go to another script and do import styleslist, well instead of giving me an option to import one variable it just does every display declaration from the other script. So, my first declaration is ||modstunoff = print("Stun: 50% less damage, but your next attack has +20% chance of hitting, has to be of the same rank however!")|| Is there a way to only call upon modstunoff rather than every variable? So instead of displaying every variable (I think there is around 15) it only displays the one that I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
import his_code  # (from his_code.py, adjust accordingly)
```

Note that this will cause his entire script to run (unless there are things inside something like an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block).

But then, from *your* script, you can access his variables:

```
print his_code.some_variable
```

or call his functions:

```
his_code.his_function(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

If you only want some of his variables / functions to be put in your namespace, you could do:

```
from his_code import some_var1, some_var2, some_var3

print some_var1  # (This is the some_var1 from his_code.py)
```

This will also execute all his code.